# Pass table name as parameter to ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have N number of tables and N number of functions. All functions have same code only table name changes. Can I make a common function to be used by all of these function.

Something like this

```
def funcN
  common_func(tableN)
end

private

def common_func(tablename)
  "Some Code"
end
```

I know there may be multiple ways.. **What are the possible ways to do it?**

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Just pass a table name as an argument to `funcN`:

```
def funcN(tableN)
  common_func(tableN)
end

private

def common_func(tablename)
  "Some Code"
end
```

> What are all the possible ways to do it?

Theoretically there are indefinite number of ways to solve some problem, so you will never get an answer to this question.

P.S. Your naming does not follow the conventions. Here is how it would look if it did:

```
def func_n(table_name)
  common_func(table_name)
end

private

def common_func(table_name)
  # code omitted
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If model name is static in `funcN` then just pass it as the `string` for example consider `post` then `funcN("Post")` or from a rails record `funcN(@record.class.to_s)`

in private method catch the string param as yours `tablename` and you can convert it into model by `myModel = tablename.constantize`

then you can carry on with your line of code on that model `myModel`

Comment: What is meant by static model name? I got the error once but I am not getting it now. Can u explain so that I can understand what I did wrong at that time?

Comment: I mean if you aware of the model name you want to pass will be static where as fetching it from a active record and passing will be dynamic one.

for example if model name is post that is for sure then you can pass it statically like funcName("Post")

Answer (score 0):

If the function, usually called a method in Ruby, is inside a model it can reference the table_name. You can share the common code using a module and including it in each model which needs it, such as:

```
class Person < AR::Base
  include CommonCode
end

class Fruit < AR::Base
  include CommonCode
end

module CommonCode
  def do_something
    self.table_name
  end
end

Person.new.do_something # => 'people'
Fruit.new.do_something # => 'fruits'
```